# Trouble with Java decimal to binary converter

Tags: java, binary

I am learning Java and have been trying to build this converter for more than a week, but this attempt sometimes leaves out a necessary 0 and also does not give a result for the input "1".

this code has imported javax.swing.*; // allows for "JOptionPane.showInputDialog", a request for typed information plus a message

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        char number;
        int input, length;
        String reversedBinary = "", binary = "";

        input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                ("What number would you like converted to binary?")); // Requesting user to give input

        do {   // gets the reversed binary. For instance: 5 = 101
            reversedBinary = reversedBinary + "" + input % 2;
            input = input/2;
        } while (input > 0);

        length = reversedBinary.length();
        length--; // getting the usable position numbers instead of having length give me the position one ahead

        while (length > 0) { // some code to reverse the string
            number = reversedBinary.charAt(length);
            binary = binary + number;
            length--; // "reversedBinary" is reversed and the result is input into "binary"
        }
        System.out.print("The number converted to binary is: " + binary); // output result
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you collect the binary digits in reverse? You could just do binary = "" + (input % 2) + binary;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this shall work.

```
    input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog
            ("What number would you like converted to binary?")); // Requesting user to give input
    String BinaryStr="";
    int i = 0;
    while (input > 0){   
        BinaryStr= BinaryStr+  input % 2; 
        input = input/2;
        i++; 
    } 
    for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) 
        System.out.print(BinaryStr.charAt(j));
```